# Wordpress and Raty.js

Tags: jquery, wp-enqueue-script, custom-post-type-archives

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide.  I am trying to implement `raty.js` into a archive template for a custom post type I have created.  As far as I understand I only need to enqueue the `jquery.raty.js` file and `jquery.raty.css` files.
So I have on my child theme `functions.php`

```
function jose_scripts() {
  wp_enqueue_style( 'raty-css', get_stylesheet_directory() . '/raty/lib/jquery.raty.css' );
  wp_register_script( 'raty-js', get_stylesheet_directory() . '/raty/lib/jquery.raty.js', array('jquery'),false,true);
  wp_enqueue_script('raty-js');
  }
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'jose_scripts' );
```

I sent it to the footer so it would load waaaaay after JQuery, still I get JQuery is not defined when I put

```
JQuery('div').raty({ score: 3 });
```

I see the `jquery.raty.js` file being called on the footer.  And the `JQuery.js` on the head. I used JQuery because $ gives me the same error.
The odd thing as well is that `jquery.raty.js` is also giving this error Uncaught

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token < travelgfs.com/:259 Uncaught TypeError:
>   $ is not a function

Comment: `get_stylesheet_directory` is the server path, you want `get_stylesheet_directory_uri`.

Comment: Ok I changed to directory_uri but I am still getting JQuery is not defined but thank you for correcting that.  If it helps this is the link to the page I am trying to correct http://travelgfs.com/testimonials/

Comment: your theme looks like it's including multiple copies of jquery. you also need to wrap your code in a document.ready handler, and it should be enqueued after your script and not directly within the content.

Answer (score 0):

It's `jQuery` not `JQuery`.

Try `jQuery('div').raty({ score: 3 });`